# Confusing Return Statements in Python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, recursion

I'm failing to understand why the return statements are not returning the sorted value ?

I'm trying to sort a list ( doesn't contain a repeated number ) where I'm trying to push the smallest number to the left, and the largest to the right, post that the list in between is split and same function is called again.

```
def max_sort(i):
    if i == []:
        return []
    else:
        [min_val, max_val] = [min(i), max(i)]
        min_pos = i.index(min(i))
        max_pos = i.index(max(i))
        '''for sorting in ascending order only, min val moves to left, max val moves to right'''
        if min_pos == 0 and max_pos == len(i) - 1:
            i = i[1:-1]
            return [min_val] + [max_sort(i)] + [max_val]
        elif min_pos == 0:
            i = i[1:]
            return [min_val] + max_sort(i)
        elif max_pos == len(i) - 1:
            i = i[:-1]
            return [max_sort(i)] + [max_val]
        else:
            min_pos_copy = min_pos
            for x in range(0, min_pos_copy):
                i[min_pos] = i[min_pos - 1]
                i[min_pos - 1] = min_val
                min_pos = i.index(min(i))
            max_pos = i.index(max(i))
            max_pos_copy = max_pos
            for y in range(max_pos_copy, len(i)-1):
                i[max_pos] = i[max_pos + 1]
                i[max_pos + 1] = max_val
                max_pos = i.index(max(i))
            max_sort(i)

max_sort([22, 876, 4, 101, 7, 0])
```

It goes down to the level of splitting the correct sequence, however does not SPLICE it back up. Why ?

Comment: Is this some variant of quicksort or merge sort?

Comment: :) Don't really know, just thought if this could work...

Comment: Let me guess, you're getting None as an output because you don't return in the final case? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: I was just curious what algorithm or logic you are trying to follow. You do have a trailing `max_sort(i)` in the `else` that isn't returned.

Comment: Let me fire it again and put it as MCVE

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, that's the thing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in the code. First since `max_sort` is supposed to return `list` you don't need to assign the return value to a new list. So instead of `return [max_sort(i)] + [max_val]` just use `return max_sort(i) + [max_val]`. There are couple such cases in your code.

The other problem is that `else` branch doesn't return anything. This can be easily fixed by changing the last line in the function to `return max_sort(i)`. With these changes your code should work as expected.

Comment: OMG, thats the thing !